# What .net framework and mcr version are required for mwArray.dll (64 bit)?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to compile a simple application in C#, with reference to MWArray.
I get :

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception. ....

I tried many solutions I read over the net, and I still keep getting this error.
I think it has something to do with either the 64-bit or with the .new Framework.

Will be thankful for a working example, or for list of setting/configuration to make it work.

Many thanks!

Here is the code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                MWNumericArray matrix = new MWNumericArray();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                Console.Read();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the exception?

Comment: {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception. ...

Comment: Right, it's the bit after the ellipses that's relevant. The bit you pasted just says which object threw the exception in question.